# How do I get rid of that background noise that sounds like microphone white?

Tags: noise

Here are two videos made by same person.

The [first one](https://youtu.be/wfr4XbR5VP8?list=PLUl4u3cNGP60UlabZBeeqOuoLuj_KNphQ) comes with some kind of background noise that sounds like microphone or computer fan while [the other](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpW0ZJ7i0oc&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60UlabZBeeqOuoLuj_KNphQ&index=4) doesn't.

Considering the videos are not made by me, how do I determine if it is microphone white noise?

How do I get rid of that background noise from the video file that I download from the link above?

Comment: Get rid of it, or eliminate it *before* it goes on the recording? One way for the former would be to use a graphic eq., and re-record defeating that particular frequency. Trouble is, then anything else at that same frequency will be defeated.

Comment: @Tim Thank you. I just updated. I'm trying to get rid of that background noise from the video file that I download from the link above

Comment: @Tim the problem with EQing away noise is that it's not a single frequency but wide range.

Comment: There's a great analog tool, the Burwen Dynamic Filter ( sold under other names from maybe 1970 to 1985 or so) but it depends on having an analog stereo input.  I don't know any way other than a steep passband filter to remove white noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble with this type of issue is it's very easy to make in the first place [stick a really cheap computer headset straight into the headset jack on a PC], but *really* difficult & expensive to fix *properly* afterwards.

You can remove the noise completely using something like [IZotope RX](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/rx.html), but what you're left with is still an abysmal mic sound… just without the noise. It's not worth the effort [I know, I just tried it using the above-mentioned really expensive software;)

[image]

I checked at IZotope & the Voice Denoise plugin is actually in the basic entry-level version, so you *could* do this for $£€ 30, but it's not really worth even that, tbh.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a de-noiser program.  But 'white noise' mush is the hardest type of noise to analyse and cancel, because it contains such a wide range of frequencies.  Anyway, background noise is the least of your problems in these videos.   If audio quality matters, re-record the voiceover.  If the original voice must be retained, perhaps for historical reasons, just live with the original.  Though distorted, it's pretty intelligible, particularly with the subtitles!